# No such file or directoryError in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection, what solution do you have for this Error?

Tags: java, r, directory, osmosis, osmar

I am a new R-user and currently face a problem with Osmar package while I am running the chunk:

```
osm_file_path <- "~/Downloads/berlin-latest.osm"
src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "/Users/Soodi/Downloads/berlin-latest.osm")
ber_bbox <- center_bbox(13.3888599,52.5170365,3000,3000)
ber <- get_osm(ber_bbox, src)
```

the error that  has been showed up is:

'"java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Soodi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpox4c9R\file13a075721e7c': No such file or directoryError in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

While, in cmd, I have checked both Java and osmosis to be correctly installed and I have already added their path to environment variables.the temp file which is in the error description does not exist on my laptop, and I am wondering what else could be the problem.

I really appreciate any help or clue regarding this matter.
Cheers, 
Soodi